# Why is it the postposition を used here instead of の?

Tags: particle-を

> 悲鳴と銃声と爆音の狂想曲は絶え間なく、かつ容赦なく鳴り響き、**街を人を**根こそぎ壊し、鏖殺｛おうさつ｝していく。「[ディエス・イレ](https://vndb.org/v548)」

Basic structure to me seems to be X狂想曲はA鳴り響き、B根こそぎ壊し、鏖殺していく, a subject 狂想曲 with three verbals (X and A,　B being their respective pre-noun and pre-verbal elements). 根こそぎ壊し、鏖殺していく seem to share the same pre-verbal as their object - "the people of the city"(?)).

What I don't understand is the bolded pre-verbal B. **Why is it the postposition を used here instead of の?**

NB**one could argue how far the adverbial 絶え間なく、かつ容赦なく applies but that seems to be ambiguous [(?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23845/how-do-adverbs-work-with-multiple-clauses-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part 街を人を simply isn't "the people of the city", but two parallel objects: "the city, the people (accusative)".

In English you have to put a comma between them but Japanese orthography doesn't require it. Japanese commas are not for indicating grammatical structure; they basically just mark where to pause. Thus, you can't place too much confidence in them while parsing sentences.

You can't decide how far 絶え間なく、かつ容赦なく could reach by pure grammar. But my what little esthetic sense tells that it can't go over the next heavy adverbial chunk 街を人を根こそぎ, so its effect must be limited to 鳴り響き right after it.